# Issue using rails generator controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, generator

I'm completely new to rails and mostly new to web development in general. i'm trying to create a whole new tab within a page on our website. I'm trying to emulate as much as possible a tab that's already built out in our application. I noticed that there was a controller and a view associated with the tab i'm trying to emulate so I used the rails generator to create a controller for the tab (which will contain a report) i'm trying to build. So I ran generator through RubyMine (tools -> Run Rails Generator...), gave it the name i wanted to use, `RejectedOffersReportController`, and used `show` and `initialize` as the two actions. Incidentally, the tab i'm trying to emulate has both of those methods in the controller but only has a view for show - i'm not sure what that means exactly.

In any case, back to the matter at hand - first of all, when I go to the page where i expect the tab to be, the tab isn't there. Secondly, when I try to manually navigate (i.e. put the address in manually - `localhost:3000/admin/rejected_offers_report`) I get the following message in my browser:

> Routing Error
>
> uninitialized constant Admin::RejectedOffersReportsController

the bizarre part is that `RejectedOffersReportsController` is not anywhere to be found in my project when I do a project-wide search in the RubyMine IDE. (Notice the plural form of reports which is not the name i used in the controller generator).

Any and all help is appreciated.

UPDATE: ok, so i get why initialize isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers default to the pluralized form of the class name. Just rename your controller file/class to `RejectedOffersReportsController`.

It's easier just to go along with the Rails conventions unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: changed the controller name to plural and it's starting to work. The tab is being displayed and I can click on it (though i'm getting errors in the page when I do click on it for now).